# How to get last inserted row id with stored procedure mapping using transaction and entity 6?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, transactions

I have two tables: `Log` and `CustomerRow`. I'm using Entity Framework 6 and some stored procedure mapped to them separately and The Transaction for inserting for each one.

Normally I can insert data without any problem, but I want to use transaction for commit changes, so when I call `db.SaveChanges()` after inserting to table `CustomerRow`, I need this inserted row id for inserting into `Log table`, but the inserted row id always  is 0, because the Transaction is still not committed.

The two tables are not linked.

I know that, I can use stored procedure directly and use the returned identity value for other insert, but I need to insert  simultaneously for two tables using transaction.

Is there any way to get through it?

This is my code:

```
using (var db=new KavirPreSellEntities())
        {
            using (var transaction=db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var customerRow = new Customers_Rows
                    {
                        CustomerRow_Number = 1360,
                        CustomerRow_Year=DateTime.Now.Year,
                        CustomerRow_Weight = 250
                    };
                    db.Customers_Rows.Add(customerRow);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    var log = new Log
                    {
                        Log_FlagID = 1,
                        Log_DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        Log_TablesID = 2,
                        Log_UserID = MyClass.User.User_ID,
                        Log_RowID = customerRow.CustomerRow_ID //this is always 0
                    };
                    db.Log.Add(log);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exception.GetBaseException().Message);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi why not to do this also in SP you already mentioned you are using Sp so you can idealy use loging in side SP there you ca nuse @ScopeIdentity to get the current row id and pass required parameter to that sproc .

Comment: Yes you are right, but I want to know is there any way by this scenario or not